# Initialize a vector inside a struct vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a vector of structs that contain a vector, and i don't know how to initialize the fields inside the struct.
I have the following code:

```
struct member {
  vector<pair<int, int> > rival_result;
  int matches;
}
vector<member> ranking(n);
```

I want to set the size of the vector inside the struct to the size of the other vector and have 0 in all the fields(matches and the integers of the pair vector).
N can be a very big number so it can't be done manually.
Thanks.

Comment: C++11 or later allowed? Also, can the size change after initialisation / must it be set at runtime?

Comment: Can't use c++ 11, and the size can't change after the initialization, for more info, this code is a private member of a class and i ned to initialize it on 0 for the creator function which is:
Ranking::Ranking(int n);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a constructor for `member` first that sets the size of your vector:

```
struct member {
    explicit member (int n) : rival_result(n), matches(0) { }
    vector<pair<int, int> > rival_result;
    int matches;
};
```

Now create your vector:

```
vector<member> ranking(n, member(n));
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about the explicit specifier, tomorrow i will ask my teacher if i can use it on my code, they are very restrictive about we can ad can't use.

Comment: @flapedriza Using `explicit` is optional here. It prevents the compiler from treating the constructor as defining an implicit conversion from `int` to `member`, which can be the source of bugs. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) has the details.